# How to create temporal session like php in Android studio

Tags: android

I want a way to create a session in Android studio like php to pass string from  one activity to another on within the same activity

Comment: You have to put `Extras` in the first activity and then, get that extra in the second one. [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters)

Answer (score 0):

you can use *`intent.putExtras`* but i usually use a static class to act like a session and store the info i want. I simply call Storage.user to retrieve the values.

```
public class Storage {
    public static User user;
    public static String name;
    public static boolean change;
    public static String place;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass data between activities you can use `Intent`

```
String myData="Your string/data here";
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);    
intent.putExtra("your_key",myData);
startActivity(intent);
```

Access that intent on next `activity`:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String myData = extras.getString("your_key");
}
```